# Android Studio rendering exception: "mBaselineAlignedChildIndex of LinearLayout points to a View that doesn't know how to get its baseline"

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

What the cause of this design view error in Android Studio?

Exception raised during rendering: `mBaselineAlignedChildIndex of LinearLayout points to a View that doesn't know how to get its baseline`.

Here's the layout:

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mainListView"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_btm_actionbar"
                android:src="@mipmap/ab_solid_example"/>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/eventStates"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/listviewimg"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
                android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_cancel_callresult"
                    android:layout_width="153dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"                             android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_padding_material"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:onClick="cancelCallResult"
                    android:text="Cancel"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />



            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Did you get the solution for the same? I am facing similar issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just had this same error. Baseline-alignment has to do with the parent LinearLayout determining the baseline of each child, and specifically, the last child in the layout. My issue involved a TimePicker - in API 21+, it's a graphical clock, so there are no TextViews to provide baseline information.

Here, the problem is in lines 27-35:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel_callresult"
            android:layout_width="153dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

You're missing an "android:orientation=vertical" (or horizontal) on this inner LinearLayout around the Button, **and** the Button itself specifies a gravity within its parent ("linear-gravity") of "bottom". There's no orientation or height specified for any of it, so the outer LinearLayout doesn't know how to determine a baseline for it.

Also, that inner LinearLayout is unnecessary as-is. If you want an empty space between the List and the Button, try using a [Space](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html) widget, or if you want the List to fill the space all the way to the Button, give the List a weight attribute ("layout-weight=1.0").

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but for people who run into this problem, this is a known bug, lookup "Issue 214062".
It has been resolved in API 24.

It is only a problem on the Android Studio preview tab, not on the actual emulator or device, when TimePicker visibility is gone.
To fix this issue, use tools namespace as quickfix, so that at least you'll be able to see the preview, while still being hidden on a device, like so:

```
<TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timerpicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        />
```